# have "A scan line is too wide" problem on pycharm

Tags: pygame, pycharm

I'm trying to create a border for my game and I used this code here

https://pastebin.com/ `pqeagStF`

and it gives me this error message

> File "D:/Users/44749/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Game.py", line
>   229, in 
>       game_initialize()   File "D:/Users/44749/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Game.py", line 185, in
>   game_initialize
>       SURFACE_MAIN = pygame.display.set_mode( (Constants.GAME_WIDTH*Constants.CELL_WIDTH,Constants.GAME_HEIGHT*Constants.GAME_HEIGHT
>   ) ) pygame.error: A scanline is too wide

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "a scanline is too wide" basically means you are trying to create a window that is too large for pygame to handle.

In your case this would mean that `Constants.GAME_WIDTH * Constants.CELL_WIDTH` as well as `Constants.GAME_HEIGHT * Constants.GAME_HEIGHT` are too large.

Changing them to smaller values will fix the problem.

ps. when posting code, remember to also post the files you are importing. In this case I can't see what the `GAME_HEIGHT`,`GAME_WIDTH`, `CELL_WIDTH`, `CELL_HEIGHT` values are, since they are saved in `Constants.py`.